# Units of coefficients in Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, dimensional-analysis

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is defined as

$$ \frac{d}{dt}x(t) = -\frac{1}{\mu}x + \sqrt{\frac{2\sigma^2}{\mu}}\xi(t) $$

where $\xi(t)$ is a unit white noise.

What are the units the parameters? Lets say $x$ is dimensionless. Then the left-hand side must have dimensions 1/time, which means $\mu$ must have units of time.

Now if $\xi$ is also dimensionless, then $\sigma^2$ must have units 1\time. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, looks ok to me.

Comment: Is $\xi$ dimensionless? The units 1/time for $\sigma^2$ seems wrong to me.

Comment: I have no idea of the context. You wrote 'Now if $\xi$ is also dimensionless, then $\sigma^2$ must have unit 1/time', which makes sense to me. I just answered your question.

Comment: I am wondering if $\xi$ has intrinsic dimensions. For example, from Ito calculus, we know that $dW^2 = dt$, so the Wiener process has dimensions $\sqrt{time}$. Does this mean that $\xi$ must have dimensions $1/\sqrt{time}$?